# Difficulty Bonuses for AI in Civ:Beyond Earth

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

If you choose a higher difficulty in Civ:Beyond Earth, the AI gets several bonuses. But I can't see a list of what these bonuses actually are. Ingame, it is simply stated that the AI has some advantages.

I've found lists like [this](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_level_(Civ5)) for previous games, but for the new Civ with some new mechanics there are obviously new bonuses. For example I've heard (no source) that AI will start the first city with population 3 instead of having additional settlers. In my games I've also seen player disadvantages not to be as severe as in Civ5. In my game on the lowest difficulty, I had like "+12 Health for Difficulty" and in my game on Apollo difficulty it was something around "+9 Health for Difficulty".

Has somebody already gathered some data?

Comment: Unsourced wiki link does not constitute an answer I think, but it's something - http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_level_(CivBE)

Comment: I don't own Beyond Earth, but I would be surprised if it didn't use the same system as Civ 5 where all these constants are defined in INI files that can be found and read.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Deltharis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/106692/deltharis)' comment [this wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_level_(CivBE)) lists the impact of the difficulty levels. I've found the source for the information.

**CivBEHandicapInfos.xml** File located in (typically) **C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization Beyond Earth\assets\Gameplay\XML\GameInfo\**. There is a (older) version of the file available [here](http://pastebin.com/EyVTq5pe).

From my current (Oct 27, 2015) version of the file, I have been working on making the full table, image included below. I have marked differences I noticed from the wiki version in bold. The AI bonuses are in rows 23, 26-47, with your difficulty being a column of B to G. For example, **G27** indicates the AI will recieve 1 starting colonist on Apollo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've personally noticed the AI starts with 3 combat rovers, 2 workers, a colonist, and 1 in each of the affinity levels on Apollo. I do not know what the bonuses for them are on the easier difficulties, but I've only managed to beat them on Soyuz difficulty.

Comment: While personal views are great, this answer seems more a comment and does not show repeatable, factual support. If you have more support or developer comments as per the game's code and/or support location you are welcome to edit your answer to make it more trustworthy. Welcome to Arqade!